# Import lots of mysqldumps with missing CREATE DATABASE

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I have a bunch of mysqldumps of my old server with one database each.

Unfortunately we forgot to add

```
CREATE DATABASE ...
```

in all those dumps.

How can I import those files in one batch?

Answer (score 1):

This script creates all databases accordingly to the names of the files:

```
PW=your password here
for i in *.sql; do db=$(echo $i|sed s/.sql$//;); 
  echo $db ...; 
  mysql -u root -p$PW -e "create database $db"; 
  mysql $db -u root -p$PW < $i; 
done
```